# How to check if user story was updated?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to create a logic app around a query that checks if user stories have been updated in the last 24 hours and notify user otherwise, but if I use the state as my clause, anything contributes to the state and it wont be accurate to TRUE updates (e.g. comments).

How should I approach this? Is "ChangedDate" the best field to check for updated stories and then remind the user to update the story after 24 hours have passed? Or is there a better condition I can use that checks for legitimate user story updates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ChangedDate` is enough.

`ChangedDate` can filter out all changed work items including state change and comments add records. it can achieve your requirement.

E.G:
`Created Date >= @StartOfDay - 1`

[image]

To remind users to update user stories regularly, we can try to install extensions like [Scheduled Work Item Query](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Quadrotech.ADOScheduledWorkItemQuery), then create a pipeline using the extension task to send the query result to team members. We can [Configure schedules for pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to trigger the pipeline based on your requirement, for example every 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Is there a better way to use this as a rule to remind users to update user stories at least once a day or logic app is the best approach here?

Comment: @Cataster No experience on logic app. However, we can try to install extensions like [Scheduled Work Item Query](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Quadrotech.ADOScheduledWorkItemQuery), then create a pipeline using the extension task to send the query result to team members. You can [Configure schedules for pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/scheduled-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to trigger the pipeline based on your requirement, for example every 24 hours.